# Is it possible to include c# definitions inside summary comments?

Tags: c#, comments

Is it possible to use a c# definition inside a summary comment?
Instead of **List of Objects**

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a List of Objects given a Table ID
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p_Table">The Table name to search for</param>
/// <param name="p_Id">The ID field within the p_Table to search for</param>
/// <param name="ObjectList">A List of Objects as an out parameter</param>
/// <returns>A List of Objects</returns>
```

I'd like to specifically use **`List<Object>`** inside the summary

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a List<Objects> given a Table ID
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p_Table">The Table name to search for</param>
/// <param name="p_Id">The ID field within the p_Table to search for</param>
/// <param name="ObjectList">A List<Objects> as an out parameter</param>
/// <returns>A List<Objects></returns>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you aren't looking to create a link using the `<see cref=""/>` notation, then you have to escape the angle brackets, like so:

```
/// <returns>A List&lt;Objects&gt;</returns>
```

After all, it's still XML.

However, if you want to make a reference using the `<see cref=""/>` notation, you won't be able to specify the specific type parameter (in this case `Objects`), but you can [specify the open generic type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/11/750056.aspx), like so:

```
/// <returns>A <see cref="List{T}" /></returns>
```

This will create a link to `List<T>` in the documentation.  Unfortunately, you cant replace `T`; the XML documentation does not support that (yet, hopefully it will in the future).

Comment: Thank you /// <returns>A List&lt;Objects&gt;</returns> is exactly what I was looking for.